# Firebase Hosting with Polymer: Rewrite doesn't work as expected

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-hosting, polymer-starter-kit

I have a polymer starter kit app and added an extra static html file called extra.html.

I followed the rewrite rule as advised [in polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/deploy) and was expecting that if I navigate to [this url](https://firebaseUrl/extra.html) , it will display extra.html. However, it's always fetching index.html instead.

My firebase.json is as follows:

```
    {
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/unbundled",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "!/__/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**/!(*.js|*.html|*.css|*.json|*.svg|*.png|*.jpg|*.jpeg)",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I get it to display extra.html when i navigate to https://firebaseUrl/extra.html? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to post your folder structure? This works for me

Comment: This might help: 

https://medium.com/@scarygami/differential-serving-on-firebase-hosting-f83c33b83a8e